# Simple question: why 'list' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, pygame

I am sorry if this is simple but I can't find an answer. I am trying to get random enemies in pygame (they should be same but spawn random).

So I have class:

```
class Enemy(object): 
       def __init__(self, ...):
          ...
          self.visible = True 
    #and then I wanna make a list of this object

E1 = []
#in my while loop 
while True:
      ...
      if event.type == USEREVENT+2:
                EN1.append(Enemy(10, 20, 64, 64, 259))

      if len(enemy_bullets) < 1:
            rocks.append(ro((round(EN1.x + EN1.width//2) - 30), (round(EN1.y + EN1.height//2) - 50), 23, 23))
```

I imported `*` from `pygame.locals` and in the beginning I set

```
pygame.time.set_timer(USEREVENT+2, random.randint(1000, 5000))
```

My error is 'list' object has no attribute 'x' and if I comment this I got another error in `if E1.visible == True:` ... it says: 'list' object has no attribute 'visible'.
Why?

Comment: `EN1` is a list, maybe what you want is `EN1[index]` where `0 <= index < len(EN1)`

Answer (score 1):

Like @dcg said in the comments, EN1 is a list. You are appending to that list and then within that list you have your object of class Enemy. If you want to access a property in one of your enemy you need to index into that list (i.e. EN1[*index of your enemy*]) then access the variable inside, for example:

```
EN1[index].x
```

Comment: Then I got  `global name 'index' is not defined`, by the way i want to make it to spaw random so that pc could spawn it between 1-5 seconds(it should spawn random number of enemy, so I won't know how much will it be). And if i try EN1.index[x], I got same error **global name 'x' is not defined**.

Comment: Well here the index is not a variable in your program. Which enemy in the list is the one you want to get? If its the first name do EN1[0].x if its the last one you do EN1[-1].x.

Comment: Not working, if i do that then I got **list index out of range**

Comment: What is the index you use and what is the size of your list when you do that?